# Did the Israeli soldiers who were involved in Operation Protective Edge eliminate any parts of davening?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, army-military-war, current-events, danger

I assume that those driving the tanks, going in the tunnels, and otherwise in immediate dangerous situations either completely miss a prayer, or eliminate parts of it. Maybe they are saying "Havinenu" instead of Shmoneh Esreh?

If anyone has been (or is) a Chayal (soldier) I'm curious as to what is done regarding daily tefillah.

Comment: In life threatening situations you omit everything!

Comment: [This site](http://www.aka.idf.il/Main/rabanut/faq.aspx?catId=59732) tells how to deal with problems of lack of time for tefillo on Rosh Hashono (under האם ישנם חלקים מתפילת ראש השנה שניתן לדלג עליהם במצב של עומס בפעילות המבצעית?)

Comment: There's a short tfilla in Bavli Brachot 29a to say in dangerous situations. It has a shem but not malchut; see http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=29b&format=text. Havineinu takes some time because it includes the first 3 and last 3 brachot.

Comment: @Scimonster Wow! Some time ago. I guess it pays to search the "attic" every so often. I up-voted a while ago; just accepted. Thanks for the reminder. Don't be an ogre to science - without it, there'd be far fewer theories ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Last night, i asked this question of someone who served in the war. He said that when they were in the field, there was no time for davening, and he didn't say that they said the extremely short version, so i assume they didn't. On the base for a break, they were able to daven, but not everyone was able to put on tefillin. He didn't say exactly why not; perhaps it was because they didn't know whether they would have to run out again.